# How to write multiple for loops in one line of if condition in python? (specific to DOCX)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have the following code.

```
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        if cell.tables:
            <some code>
        else:
            <different code>
```

But I need it to be written in one line as below so that the `<different code>` in `else` will run only once and not multiple times due to the loop.

```
if any(cell.tables for cell in row.cells for row in table.rows):
    <some code>
else:
    <different code>
```

However, this one liner is showing **Unresolved reference 'row'** error at *row.cells*. This one liner works but have no idea why it doesn't in this docx table case.
I'm also open for suggestions if this can be done in a different and better way apart from the one liner if condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have your `for` clauses reversed. You are trying to reference `row` in the first `for` clause and then define it in the second. That's why it doesn't work.

You mean

```py
if any(cell.tables for row in table.rows for cell in row.cells):
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, but it's weird. It had worked for me in the past. But not sure why this takes the for clauses in the way you've suggested. Thanks!

Comment: The `for` clauses in a nested expression like this need to appear in the same order they would if you were nesting them in indented lines of code. The outside for loop goes first, inside next, etc. That makes it easy to remember the order you need :)

Answer (score 2):

you can make something called nested list function in python.

look at this example:

```
iter1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
iter2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for x in iter1:
    for y in iter2:
        print(x, y)

print("------")
# Method 1: Nested List Comprehension
[print(x, y) for x in iter1 for y in iter2]
print("------")
# Method 2: exec()
exec("for x in iter1:\n    for y in iter2:\n        print(x, y)")
print("------")
# Method 3: For Loop with List Comprehension
for x in iter1: [print(x, y) for y in iter2]
```

all examples reproduce the following output:

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
3 a
3 b
3 c
4 a
4 b
4 c
```

in you case you should you this:

you need to put a condition element:

```
for x in iter1: [print(x, y) for y in iter2 if y=='a']
```

Comment: This is a little complex to me as I'm not very proficient in python (yet). Will definitely try this after I understand it thoroughly. Thank You! :)